# Drawing on a transparent CWnd DC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, mfc

I'm attempting to create a transparent CWnd on top of an MFC dialog so that I can bitblt bitmaps to the dialog dc and then separately draw shapes to the transparent DC that sits directly on top of the dialog. The issue is, I can't seem to get the CWnd to be transparent. Instead, whenever I blit a black bitmap to the transparent CWnd, it flickers with the dialog... as if one were to blit the dialog dc and then immediately after blit a black bitmap to the same DC.

For instance, on the dialog I create a CWnd object that will be the transparent overlay:

```
pDrawingWnd = new CWnd();
pDrawingWnd->Create(NULL, L"", WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, IMAGEX, IMAGEY), this, 0);
pDrawingWnd->ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
pDrawingWnd->SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(0,0,0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Then, in a timer loop, I draw a rectangle to the CWnd DC:

```
CDC mDC;
pDC = pDrawingWnd->GetDC();

mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

if (drawingBmp)
    delete drawingBmp;

drawingBmp = new CBitmap();
drawingBmp->CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, IMAGEX, IMAGEY);
CBitmap* pOldBmp2 = mDC.SelectObject(drawingBmp);

mDC.FrameRect(CRect(0,0,100,100), &brush);
pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, IMAGEX, IMAGEY, &mDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

mDC.SelectObject(pOldBmp2);
ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

So instead of drawing a green rectangle on top of the dialog, it just flickers displaying the black bitmap with the green rectangle. Normally I would draw the rectangle directly to the dialog dc, however when I have a slower update rate, let's say 10 times per second.. it updates the size of the rectangle slowly. So I would rather the drawing of the rectangle be independent of the blit rate on the dialog. What's the correct way to draw on top of another DC?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [layered window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) with per pixel alpha.

Comment: That is being done with:
pDrawingWnd->ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);

Comment: @Goober but not with per pixel alpha. You cannot use compatible bitmap there, only bitmaps with alpha can be used for that (32-bit dib)